# sintaxis error that i can t understand with port map

Tags: vhdl, vivado

i am trying to do a fulladder of 4 bits from a fulladder 1bit but the plataform vivado that i am using give a syntaxis error but i don t know why?
 here is the first module (the name is HA2(Fulladder1bits(i have to change the letters HA2 for FA but i know how to do it yet)))

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
entity HA2 is
    Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC;
           b : in  STD_LOGIC;
           s : out  STD_LOGIC;
           cin : in  STD_LOGIC;
           count : out  STD_LOGIC);
end HA2;

architecture Behavioral of HA2 is

begin

s <= a xor b xor cin;
count <= (a and b) or (cin and (a or b));

end Behavioral;
```

and the error is in this next module (named "fulladder4bits" ) :

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
entity fulladder4bits is
    Port ( A : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           B : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           S : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           C3 : out STD_LOGIC);
end fulladder4bits;

architecture Behavioral of fulladder4bits is

COMPONENT HA2
    Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC;
           b : in  STD_LOGIC;
           s : out  STD_LOGIC;
           cin : in  STD_LOGIC;
           count : out  STD_LOGIC);
end COMPONENT;
signal C0,C1,C2 : std_logic ;
begin

fa1 : HA2 port map(A(0),B(0),'0',S(0),C0) ;**HERE the plataform vivado give me a syntaxis error but i don t know why 
fa2 : HA2 port map(A(1),B(1),'C0',S(1),C1) ;**HERE 
fa3 : HA2 port map(A(2),B(2),'C1',S(2),C2) ;**HERE 
fa4 : HA2 port map(A(3),B(3),'C2',S(3),C3) ;**HERE 

end Behavioral;
```

however with the errors and everything i could do the synthesis and the implementation so i really don t know what is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the ports in the component is important. Instantiate has used with another order. The order of `s` and `cin` is not correct. Therefore, you can use to way to solve problem.

```
fa1: HA2 port map(A(0), B(0), S(0),'0', C0);
fa2: HA2 port map(A(1), B(1), S(1), C0, C1);
fa3: HA2 port map(A(2), B(2), S(2), C1, C2);
fa4: HA2 port map(A(3), B(3), S(3), C2, C3);
```

or (this way is better choice)

```
fa0:HA2 port map(a=>A(0), b=>B(0), cin=>'0', s=>S(0), count=>C0);
fa1:HA2 port map(a=>A(1), b=>B(1), cin=>C0, s=>S(1), count=>C1);
fa2:HA2 port map(a=>A(2), b=>B(2), cin=>C1, s=>S(2), count=>C2);
fa3:HA2 port map(a=>A(3), b=>B(3), cin=>C2, s=>S(3), count=>C3);
```

> The second problem of your code is 'C0' ('C1', 'C2') in port map. it
>   should be C0 (C1, C2).

Answer (score 0):

this solve my problem but i really don t know why :

```
fa0:HA2 port map(a=>A(0),b=>B(0),cin=>'0',s=>S(0),count=>C0);
fa1:HA2 port map(a=>A(1),b=>B(1),cin=>C0,s=>S(1),count=>C1);
fa2:HA2 port map(a=>A(2),b=>B(2),cin=>C1,s=>S(2),count=>C2);
fa3:HA2 port map(a=>A(3),b=>B(3),cin=>C2,s=>S(3),count=>C3);
```

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.7 Association lists  6.5.7.1 "An association element is said to be *named* if the formal designator appears explicitly; otherwise, it is said to be *positional*. For a positional association, an actual designator at a given position in an association list corresponds to the interface element at the same position in the interface list. Named associations can be given in any order, ..." The positional order in your question is incorrect. The named associations can be in any given order as here.